# How can I perform an INNER JOIN based on matching a value contained in an array, which is itself a field of a Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently we perform an inner join on `user_table` and `keyword_table` by simply matching `user_table.id = keyword_table.userId`.

In my wisdom, I have decided to modify keyword_table, so that an individual userId is stored in an array for a particular keyword. The field, `userId`, is now an array containing userIds.

How can I perform an inner join based on `user_table.id` being included in `keyword.userId`?

Previously:

```
FROM user_table
INNER JOIN keyword_table ON user_table.id = keyword_table.userID
```

Now:

```
FROM user_table
INNER JOIN keyword_table ON user_table.id included in keyword_table.userID
```

I am aware of `IN` operator, but I am unsure of how this can be of use in a inner join. I am not using any foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `>@`:

```
FROM user_table ut INNER JOIN
     keyword_table kt
     ON kt.userID @> ARRAY[ut.id]
```

Or:

```
     ON array_position(kt.userID, ut.id) > 0
```

Or:

```
     ON u.id = any(kt.userID, ut.id)
```

Or, what I would more typically do:

```
FROM user_table ut INNER JOIN
     keyword_table kt JOIN
     unnest(kt.userId) u(userId)
     ON u.userID = ut.id
```

Comment: Why do you prefer the third example?

Comment: @Sandbagger . . . I like the `=`.  Arcane syntax such as `>@` is hard (for me) to remember.  And the use of a function call in the an `on` clause scares me (from a performance perspective).

Comment: Or `on ut.id = any(kt.userid)` that could use an array on `userid` if suitable